# Keycloak set password policy via Rest API

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api, password-policy

I would like to update/add password policy through Keycloak RestAPI.

I went through the docs, but it looks like that I may only retrieve the list of password policy through APIs. Any other possible way so that I can handle the password policy through Rest API?

https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/rest-api/index.html#_serverinforepresentation 
https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/rest-api/index.html#_passwordpolicytyperepresentation

[image: Manage Password Policy through Keycloak Admin Panel]

I am using Keycloak 11.

---

**Update:**
I managed to figure out that the password policy values are located inside the password policy column under Realm table. I think that I might need to restart Keycloak, or clear Keycloak cache
using Keycloak Rest API (POST /{realm}/clear-realm-cache) on https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/rest-api/index.html to make it work once I update the table.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** The `/auth` path was removed starting with [Keycloak 17 Quarkus distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902419/1366871). So you might need to remove the `/auth` from the endpoint calls presented on this answer.

---

You can use [Keycloak Rest API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html) to get Realm `password policies`, namely:

```
GET <KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth/admin/realms/<YOUR_REALM>
```

from the `JSON` response extract the field `passwordPolicy`. For the following policies:

[image]

you would get the following response: `length(8) and hashIterations(27500)`

To add/update a given policy call the endpoint

```
PUT <KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth/admin/realms/<YOUR_REALM>
```

with the appropriate data parameter. For instance, let us say that from the previous example you want to update the "Minimum length" policy to 10 instead of 8, then the data to be send in the `PUT` request would be:

```
'{"passwordPolicy":"length(10) and hashIterations(27500)"}'
```

For those that are interested I have scripts for the aforementioned actions in this git [repo](https://github.com/dreamcrash/StackOverflow-/tree/main/Keycloak/RestAdminAPI/Realm).

---

**Step-by-Step**

You can get that information using the [Keycloak Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html); to call that API, you need an access token from a user with the proper permissions. For now, I will be using the `admin` user from the `master` realm, but later I will explain how you can use another user:

```bash
curl "https://${KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token" \
    -d "client_id=admin-cli" \
    -d "username=${ADMIN_NAME}" \
    -d "password=${ADMIN_PASSWORD}" \
    -d "grant_type=password"
```

You get a JSON response with the admin's token. Extract the value of property `access_token` from that response. Let us save it in the variable `$ACCESS_TOKEN` for later reference.

To [get the realm information](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html#_getrealm) of `$REALM_NAME`:

```bash
curl -X GET "https://${KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/admin/realms/${REALM_NAME}" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}"
```

from the `JSON` response extract the field `passwordPolicy`.

To [set the password policies](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html#_updaterealm) of `$REALM_NAME`:

```bash
curl -X PUT "https://$KEYCLOAK_IP/auth/admin/realms/${REALM_NAME}"\
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
     -d "${JSON_PASSWORD_POLICY_DATA}"
```

**Assigning the proper user permissions**

For those that do not want to get an access token from the master admin user, you can get it from another user but that user needs the permission `view-realm` from the `realm-management` client. For that you can:

**(OLD Keycloak UI)**

- Go to Users, and then the user in question
- Go to the tab `Role Mappings`
- In `client roles` select `realm-management`
- Select the role `view-realm` and click on `Add selected`

**(New Keycloak UI)**

- Go to Users, and then the user in question
- Go to the tab `Role Mappings`
- Click on `Assign role`
- In `Search by role name` type `view-realm`
- Select the role and assign it